# Use Block in Objective C to find out if a BOOL has been set?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm new to Obj-c. I've got a class which sets a var boolean to YES if it's successful (Game Center login = successful), what it would be great to do, is somehow have a listener to that var that listens to when it is YES and then executes some code. Do I use a block for that? I'm also using the Sparrow framework.

Here's my code in my GameCenter.m file

```
-(void) setup
{
    gameCenterAuthenticationComplete = NO;

    if (!isGameCenterAPIAvailable()) {
        // Game Center is not available.
        NSLog(@"Game Center is not available.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Game Center is available.");

            __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; // removes retain cycle error

            GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer =  [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]; // localPlayer is the public GKLocalPlayer

        __weak GKLocalPlayer *weakPlayer = localPlayer; // removes retain cycle error

            weakPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
            {
                if (viewController != nil)
                {
                    [weakSelf showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable:viewController];
                }
                else if (weakPlayer.isAuthenticated)
                {
                    [weakSelf authenticatedPlayer:weakPlayer];
                }
                else
                {
                    [weakSelf disableGameCenter];
                }
            };
        }

    }

    -(void)showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable:(UIViewController *)controller
    {
        [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    -(void)authenticatedPlayer:(GKLocalPlayer *)player
    {
        NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@",player.playerID,player.displayName, player.alias);

        gameCenterAuthenticationComplete = YES;

    }

    -(void)disableGameCenter
    {

    }
```

But I need to know from a different object if that gameCenterAuthenticationComplete equals YES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a delegate pattern. It's far easier to use than KVO or local notifications and it's used a lot in Obj-C.

Notifications should be used only in specific situations (e.g. when you don't know who wants to listen or when there are more than 1 listeners).

A block would work here but the delegate does exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

You could use KVO (Key-Value Observing) to watch a property of your object, but I'd rather post a NSNotification in your case.

You'll need to have the objects interested in knowing when Game Center login happened register themselves to `NSNotificationCenter`, then post the `NSNotification` in your Game Center handler. Read the *Notification Programming Topics* for more details !

Answer (score 0):

If there is a single method to execute on a single delegate object, you can simply call it in the setter. Let me give a name to this property:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign, getter=isLogged) BOOL logged;
```

It's enough that you implement the setter:

```
- (void) setLogged: (BOOL) logged
{
    _logged=logged;
   if(logged)
       [_delegate someMethod];
}
```

Another (suggested) way is to use NSNotificationCenter. With NSNotificationCenter you can notify multiple objects. All objects that want to execute a method when the property is changes to YES have to register:

```
NSNotificationCenter* center=[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver: self selector: @selector(handleEvent:) name: @"Logged" object: nil];
```

The handleEvent: selector will be executed every time that logged changes to YES. So post a notification whenever the property changes:

```
- (void) setLogged: (BOOL) logged
{
    _logged=logged;
   if(logged)
   {
        NSNotificationCenter* center=[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center postNotificationName: @"Logged" object: self];
   }
}
```